# Searching text for geonames

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

which part of huge package nltk I must study and use, if I need mark geonames in text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use their named entity recognizer [nltk.ne_chunk](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html#named-entity-recognition).

Once the text is tagged you'll want to look for phrases labeled LOC (location) and GPE (Geo-political Entity).